# Bootstrap 3 multiple navbars

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with multiple bootstrap in Twitter Bootstrap 3. 
First Navbar is working ok with resizing and responsive.
Second navbar doesn't work properly in normal resolution, but when i try to do size to responsive and after resize it's working okay.

Here's some code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->  <!--<![endif]-->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <style>
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));


    </script>


<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
<div id="wrap">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top hr" style="background:black;">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-brand logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size:17px;">
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Item2</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Item3</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Item4</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Item</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Item6</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Item7</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top hr" style="background:#ececec; border-top:none; ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse2">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse2 collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size:17px;">
                    <li><a href="#">it1d</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">it2d</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">it3d</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">it4d</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">it5d</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">it6d</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">it7d</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- FOOTER -->
```

And Bootply:
http://bootply.com/101032

Best Regards and thanks for help.

Edit:
Ok I have resolution.

If you have same problem you have to change data target for second navbar and in starting div add ( i changed for .main-nav)
and after add your data-target class on the end of navbar item.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-nav">
```

Here's link to bootply how to do it proper

http://bootply.com/101069

Comment: thanks for posting the solution

Answer (score 1):

try changing 
`<div class="navbar-collapse2 collapse">` 
to that 
`<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">`

Comment: That will work on normal but when you change to 'responsive' width and you will click into buttons you will have 2 navbars open not only one you clicked.

Comment: ok I saw you use a one function to this same element and you called this function using this same class, for a second menu write new function -> [link]http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following bit of CSS (either in a `style` tag or a custom css file), it should fix your problem.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse2.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
}
```

I pulled this code from the code in bootstrap.css for `.navbar-collapse`