# Multiple fixed top navbar headers in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

- Bootstrap 3.02

I would like to have 2 fixed to top navbars similair to how Joomla! 3 implements their browse screen.

[image: Before you scroll]

And then once you scroll navbar #2 butts up against the top one:

[image: Second Navbar butts up against the first]

I have looked at:

- [Bootstrap 3 multiple navbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637235/bootstrap-3-multiple-navbars)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/aAGJKArh-8E

but trying multiple snippets I cannot get this to work. Can anyone help with a working demo in jsFiddle?

Comment: Can you post what you have tired so far?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [code below](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/vNecy/4/) is a basic start using two `navbars` and `affix`.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="divide-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="divide-text">Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-lower" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse-buttons">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.divide-nav{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #428bca;
}

.divide-text{
    color:#fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.affix {
  top: 50px;
  width:100%;
}

.filler{
  min-height: 2000px;
}

.navbar-form {
   padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-collapse{
   padding-left:0; 
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.navbar-lower').affix({
  offset: {top: 50}
});
```

Comment: Please consider adding the content on jsFiddle to your answer, if jsFiddle goes down this answer is useless.

Comment: I had to add `z-index: 1000;` to `.affix` to make sure content scrolled underneath the second navbar. Other than that, working just fine.

Comment: It is not working, only the top header stays. Not a valid answer.

Comment: @MohammedZackria-Zack Considering my demo works just fine and the fact that 10 people up-voted, I'm betting the issue is with your project, not my code. Did you include jQuery and the Bootstrap Javascript file in your project? Both are required(before my Javascript snippet).

Comment: @Schmalzy Jquery and bootstrap is there, only the first header is fixed. The question is both First header and second header has to be fixed like Joomla.

Comment: @MohammedZackria-Zack both navbars ARE fixed (after scrolling 50px, using the Bootstrap Affix functionality).... look at the jsFiddle mentioned in my answer.. http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/vNecy/4/ Obviously for whatever reason the Affix functionality is not working in your project, but my example works.

Comment: It is not working in JSFiddle as well. I am using Chrome Browser Version 39.0.2171.71 m on CentOS machine. Only the first header is fixed. "Some Text Here" content scrolls, which should not.

Comment: The "Some Text Here" section is equivalent to the "Category Manager: Articles" section from the OPs screenshots above, which is supposed to scroll (its gone in 2nd screenshot), Its the second navbar below the "Some Text Here" section that becomes fixed after scrolling 50px. Anyways, I give up on you, I don't think you understand the original question, or its just not working on your machine for some weird reason.

Comment: This is a great answer. How do I go about adding responsive support to the sub navbars?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <style>body { padding-top: 70px; }</style>
 </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    Top Nav
  </div>
</nav>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<img src="Desert.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</body></html>
```

[Video link](https://youtu.be/kc4ST9rFxz0)

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this :
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default>
      navbar1
  </nav>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      navbar2
  </nav>
</div>
```

This code will work for u.But when boostrap4 release i think its better to use that one.