# how to implement bootstrap multiple navbars

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've done a lot of reading and searching but I seem to be stuck. I am looking for functionality very similar to: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616381/multiple-fixed-top-navbar-headers-in-twitter-bootstrap-3) which links to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/vNecy/4/) jsfiddle.

I am looking to have one navbar that will always to fixed to the top of the page (fixed-top) and then multiple navbars will attach to the bottom of the fixed navbar as you scroll down the page. To start, two navbars will be touching.

Please see [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/oL28so2t/2/) jsfiddle. It is my attempt to solve this problem, however I am running into a scenario which I cannot fix. As you can see in the jsfiddle, when you scroll down the page, the body of the page all the sudden jumps upwards, it's not a smooth transition. You can see the numbers 1, then as you scroll, you jump to 4. My problem is there is no smooth scrolling as you scroll down the body of the page. Any help would be much appreciated in solving this problem, I feel like I am very close but there must be some trivial error.

I've had some problems pasting html code into the stackoverflow form, it is on the jsfiddle, here is also the js/css i am using.

```
$('.navbar-lower').affix({
    offset: { top: 0 }
});
```

css

```
.affix {
  top: 50px;
  width:100%;
}

body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.navbar-lower {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616381/multiple-fixed-top-navbar-headers-in-twitter-bootstrap-3?lq=1

Comment: Yes, I have read that link thoroughly, and I reference that at the top, my situation is a little more unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anyone at any point, I'll elaborate on the problem and how I solved it.

It's quite simple. Before any "affixing" there is the css property of `margin-top: 50px;` on the body of the document. When the element is "affixed" or reaches the 50px marker, the margin-top is no longer applied to the second navbar, because the second navbar now has the property of `position:fixed` and `top:50px;`. Now any element beneath the second navbar will respond to the margin of 50px and that is why the there is the random jumping.

Here is a work around that I came up with, I've tried many options, I'm hoping there is a better way

JS

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {

    var position =  $(window).scrollTop() - $('.navbar-lower').position().top ;

    if(position < 0){
        $("body").css("padding-top", 100);
    }

})
```