# Two navbars in separate rows. Want the second row to dock at the top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.

Here's the page that I want to update, http://obrary.com/about-us.  The page has two navbars.  The top one is the site navbar.  The second navbar is for the About Us section of the site.

The desired behavior of the navbar is:

- on scroll, both of the navbars scroll up
- the first navbar can scroll off of the screen
- when the second navbar gets to the top of the screen, it docs/sticky.

On my one row navbars, I doc the navbar with bootstsrap

> class="navbar-fixed-top"

But the same solution doesn't work when there are two rows of navbars.

I've set up an example in bootply here, http://www.bootply.com/XDQag4Pe5X.

Thanks

Comment: this solves your issue http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/vNecy/4/ credit goes to @Schmalzy from post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616381/multiple-fixed-top-navbar-headers-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: @blairmeister you're solution fixes the top nav.  I think Scott is looking to fix the bottom nav once it scrolls to the top of the page.  I love Bootstrap, the 85% solution.

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for the 2nd/lower navbar to affix.  @AngularJR shows the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott, The suggestion to use

```
<script>
$('.navbar-lower').affix({
  offset: {top: 50}
});
</script>
```

It works fine here in the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ah5spou/1/embedded/result/)**. Set up with your code.
The first navbar scrolls out of view then the second navbar sticks to the top.

Comment: Here it is working in the Bootply example I made, http://www.bootply.com/XDQag4Pe5X

Comment: Scott, that 's great it's working as you wanted now.